# Date Picker (MUI) not able to resize it ? any suggested way?

Tags: typescript, resize, mui-x-date-picker

Im facing question in resizing the width and height of text field of mui datepicker, did anyone have tried this before can show me?
I need to extend the length of the text field and disable the textfield for the user but they can only use the picker function

right now the Interface and simple function have been done, just need to redesign it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.